# Macros don't compile in Excel 2016 after import from 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I'm using / I have developed a VBA Add-in to be used in Excel 2010. The add-in runs as expected in 2010. In Excel 2016, however, a macro that was refreshing the available options on this add-in menu, based on the type of spreadsheet opened, doesn't get updated. I have rechecked the code and the content is the same as it was in 2010. If i try to recompile some parts of code in 2016 I get compilation errors.

The code marked with red as error is for example:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS


Attribute VB_Name = "ClsXXX"

Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False

Attribute VB_Creatable = False

Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False

Attribute VB_Exposed = False
```

What I have done until now:

- enabled running of macros in Excel 2016;
- add the location for my xlam in Excel's trusted sources;
- compared the resources used:

  Office 2010

Visual Basic For Applications  C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\VBA\VBA7\VBE7.DLL
Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE
OLE Automation  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\stdole2.tlb
Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\MSO.DLL

Office 2016

Visual Basic For Applications  C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\VBA\VBA7.1\VBE7.DLL
Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
OLE Automation  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\stdole2.tlb
Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\MSO.DLL

Some advises on how to deal with my issue?

Sincerely,

Comment: "I get compilation errors". What errors?

Comment: Compilation error in module ... This Error happens normally when the code is not compatible with the version, platform or architecture of this application.

Comment: The previous mentioned error happens if I want to fully copy a code from Excel 2010 into Excel 2016 VBA. If I make minor changes the errors doesn't get triggered.

Comment: I don't see where exactly your issue is when you already figured out what minor changes you need to change not to trigger the error. It seems that you already know how you fix your code. Also without seeing at least the code parts with the line that throw the compilation error we cannot say much.

Comment: But the issue I'm having is not with the errors is with a macro. If a take the whole VBA code from Excel 2010, were it's running as expected to Excel 2016 some parts are not working. For example the macro for menu refreshing based on the type of sheet opened doesn't  do it's job. The only time when the menu can be controled it's at the start of the macro not when you open more sheets.

Comment: VERSION 1.0 CLASS

Attribute VB_Name = "ClsXXXXXXX"

Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False

Attribute VB_Creatable = False

Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False

Attribute VB_Exposed = False

Comment: Previous mentioned is code marked with red when taken from Excel 2010 to Excel 2016.

Comment: First of all code in red has to be fixed BEFORE anything else. You cannot even start debugging before fixing that, because compiler errors need to be fixed before. After that you can start debugging. And again if you refer to a macro that does not work, how can we provide help if we don't see your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you "imported" the files the wrong way:
It seems that you copied & pasted the **contents** of the file, whereas what you should do is a real **import** of the files:

> For import right click on the ***Project Window*** and select ***Import file …***

After the import these lines …

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS   
Attribute VB_Name = "ClsXXX"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False   
Attribute VB_Creatable = False   
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False   
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
```

should not appear in the code anymore, but these lines are used as class names and attributes during the import.

Comment: Thank you Peh for your answer, however my big issue is remaining the difference between running macros on Excel 2016 and Excel 2010. I don't understand way the macros are running as expected in Excel 2010 and when I run the same macros on 2016 they don't run as expected.  Can you please help me with some advises?

Comment: Of course there are differences in the macro language, because Microsoft changed some things. And I can only repeat myself I said it already about 3 times: Show exactly the code part that throws an error, we cannot help if we don't see the code. Explain which error occurs, where, what exactly is going wrong, what you expect instead. We need very detailed information if you want us to help. Best open up a new question for that because that is some complete different question than what we have solved here.